# Why is TypedDict not compatible with matching Mapping?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

Consider the following code:

```
from typing import Any, Mapping, TypedDict


class MyDict(TypedDict):
    foo: bool


def my_func_any(a: Mapping[str, Any]) -> None:
    print(a)


def my_func_bool(a: Mapping[str, bool]) -> None:
    print(a)


d: MyDict = {
    'foo': True
}

my_func_any(d)
my_func_bool(d)  # line 21
```

This gives the following error when checked with `mypy==0.761`:

> test.py:21: error: Argument 1 to "my_func_bool" has incompatible type "MyDict"; expected "Mapping[str, bool]"

I expected both `my_func_any(d)` and `my_func_bool(d)` to be ok, yet the latter is an error. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#type-consistency):

> #### Type Consistency
>
> First, any `TypedDict` type is consistent with `Mapping[str, object]`.
>
> [...]
>
> - A `TypedDict` with all `int` values is not consistent with `Mapping[str, int]`, since there may be additional non-int values not visible through the type, due to structural subtyping. These can be accessed using the `values()` and `items()` methods in `Mapping`, for example. Example:
>
>   ```
>   class A(TypedDict):
>       x: int
>
>   class B(TypedDict):
>       x: int
>       y: str
>
>   def sum_values(m: Mapping[str, int]) -> int:
>       n = 0
>       for v in m.values():
>           n += v  # Runtime error
>       return n
>
>   def f(a: A) -> None:
>       sum_values(a)  # Error: 'A' incompatible with Mapping[str, int]
>
>   b: B = {'x': 0, 'y': 'foo'}
>   f(b)
>   ```

Comment: Is there a way to indicate that a `TypedDict` should also always be a valid `Mapping[str, int]`?